# How to remove lines with length less than 3 words?

Tags: scala, text, apache-spark

I have a corpus of millions of Documents
and I want to remove lines which their length less than 3 words,(in Scala and Spark), 
How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All depends on how you define words but assuming a very simple approach:

```
def naiveTokenizer(text: String): Array[String] = text.split("""\s+""")
def naiveWordCount(text: String): Int = naiveTokenizer(text).length

val lines = sc.textFile("README.md")
lines.filter(naiveWordCount(_) >= 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the count function. (This assumes you have `' '` as your spaces between words):

```
scala.io.Source.fromFile("myfile.txt").getLines().filter(_.count(' '==) >= 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

zero33's answer is valid if you want to keep the lines intact. However, if you want the lines tokenized also, then `flatMap` is more efficient.

```
val lines = sc.textFile("README.md")
lines.flatMap(line =>{
  val tokenized = line.split("""\s+""")
  if(tokenized.length >= 3) tokenized
  else Seq()
})
```